# Which Christian philosophers examine their understanding of Pharaoh hardening his heart?

Tags: ethics, theology

I have read many Christian commentaries on Pharaoh and they all assume he had moral responsibility for having hardened his own heart. However did Pharaoh choose his nature and nurture or did his God given nurture and nature dictate his actions? I do not ever recall reading a commentary on the Bible that looked at itself in a critical way comparing compatibilistic  and deterministic interpretations. Who should one read for a deterministic view?

Comment: This would be better directed to [Christianity.se]. But your own ignorance of Bible commentaries does not mean they don't exist. There is a huge and long history of debate over free will within Christian theology and philosophy.

Comment: @curiousdanni If in its changed form this question needs to be redirected I would be grateful for you doing it.

Comment: God directly says to Moses that "[He] will harden Pharaoh's heart" (Exodus 7:3). The ability of exegetes to make a sacred text say whatever they want will always astonish me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

St Augustine wrote extensively and subtly on free will. You might try:

Augustine, On Free Choice of the Will

ISBN 10: 0872201880 / ISBN 13: 9780872201880

Published by Createspace Independent Publishing Platform, United States, 2015.

Or more recently :

Plantinga, Alvin, The Nature Of Necessity (Clarendon Library Of Logic & Philosophy) (Clarendon Library of Logic and Philosophy)

ISBN 10: 0198244142 / ISBN 13: 9780198244141

Reisinger, Ernest C, God's Will, Man's Will, and Free Will (Paperback)

ISBN 10: 1463527527 / ISBN 13: 9781463527525

Published by Createspace Independent Publishing Platform, United States, 2011

But as has been pointed out in the Comments there is a mass of writing on Christianity and free will.

Closely connected with the idea of free will in Christianity is that of *grace*. 
Here again the literature is vast. Try :

St Augustine, On Grace and Free Will

ISBN 10: 1631740113  ISBN 13: 9781631740114
Publisher: Beloved Publishing LLC, 2014

St Thomas Aquinas, On Grace

ISBN 10: 1514732645 / ISBN 13: 9781514732649

Published by Createspace Independent Publishing Platform, United States, 2015

Comment: I bought the Reisinger book you mentioned. On page 11 it says: "fallen man.... is never compelled to sin". I would respond that our God given fallen natures do compel us. We are subject to who we are.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I suppose the orthodox reply would be that we have an inherent, humanly uncontrollable  disposition to sin (Original Sin) but that the intervention of God's grace can prevent sin in any situation for action or with regard to any mental state or act (jealousy, lust, &c.). God's grace can override any predisposition we may have. Best - Geoffrey